# How to display data in component from http service?

Tags: angular

I have a simple code in my component:

```
lunch: Lunch[] = [];

constructor(private lunchService: LunchService) {}

getLunch() {
  this.lunchService.getLunch()
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
    )
}
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getLunch();
}
```

and `console.log(data)` works fine — i get a array of lunch objects. But when i replace the code `data=>console.log(data)` =>   `data => this.lunch = data` nothing happens. No errors, no show in my html

```
<div *ngFor="let lunchItem of lunch" >
  {{lunchItem.day}}
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post what does `data` looks like when logged on console. Will be easy to find the problem if you can post you template that you used..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't attach an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see in your example your service so i cannot understand if is an api call or you are managing a static json object in your service;
The first thing that i can tell you is that you can try to rewrite
your method getLunch() in this way:

```
getLunch() {
   this.lunchService.getLunch().subscribe({
    next: (data: Lunch[]) => {
    this.lunch = data;
     }, 
    error: (error) => {
    console.log(error);
    }
   }
```

rememember to write it after the NgOnInit()
and call it in your NgOnInit()
Just for your knowledge remember that if you make a method that retrieve a data list you have to call your method with fetchLunches() for example, and not with getLunch() because you are fetching a list and not a single lunch
Let me know if your able to reach your goal with my suggestion

Comment: Of course you are right about method's naming. I put your method  (and after ngOnInit) and still have my objects in console.log      ``` this.lunchService.getLunch().subscribe({
      next: (data: Lunch[]) => {
        this.lunch = data;
        console.log(this.lunch)
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    })this.lunchService.getLunch().subscribe({
      next: (data: Lunch[]) => {
        this.lunch = data;
        console.log(this.lunch)
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }) ```   but not in html

Comment: try this <div >
  {{lunch | json}}
</div>
let me know if in your html you can see your list object

Comment: {{lunch | json}} -  [] and  {{lunch.length}} - 0. I don't know why)  And ` ngOnInit() {
    this.getLunch();
    console.log('this '+this.lunch.length);
  }``    = 0;   )))

Comment: ok maybe i've understood your problem, if you can try this
<div *ngIf="lunch && lunch.length > 0">{{lunch | json}}</div>
in your debugging console you can see only your console.log or there are other messages?

Answer (score 1):

Best approach to the streams of data is to just subscribe to them in template. Async pipe handles subscription and unsubscribes when component is "unmounted" (the component doesn't do that) - https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy.

I would do that like that:

```
class Component {
// this returns an Observable<dinners[]>
public lunch= this.lunchService.getLunch$()
// your services/di
constructor(
    private lunchService: LunchService
){}
```

}

and then in template:

```
// an async pipe that handles subscription
<ng-container *ngFor="let dinner of lunch$ | async; index as i">
    <span>{{dinner.name}}</span>
</ng-container>
```

You are trying to take out data from a stream. There is no reason for that. You could use a `tap` operator for a side effect.
Try not to create sideeffects in your application and allow your code to be more declarative (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b687kMZDXTg)